# Visual basic. Return 1 on error

Tags: excel, vba

I've found a visual basic code called FindNum, that will give you the numbers of a string containing both text and numbers.

I would really like the function to return you a number when there actually isn't any numbers included in the string. (I've made a mockup of what I had in mind). 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Aq6W.jpg

Here's the visual basic code. I would really be appreciative if anyone could help.

```
Function FindNum(parameter, Optional ignore As Variant, Optional side As Variant) As Double
Dim n
Dim i
Dim p
i = 0
If IsMissing(ignore) = True Then
    p = parameter
Else

    If side = 1 Then
        p = Right(parameter, (Len(parameter) - Len(ignore)))

    ElseIf side = 0 Then
        p = Left(parameter, (Len(parameter) - Len(ignore)))
    Else
        p = parameter

    End If
End If
If IsNumeric(Left(p, (Len(p) - (Len(p) - 1)))) = True Then
        Do
                n = Left(p, (Len(p) - i))
                i = i + 1
        Loop Until IsNumeric(n) = True
        FindNum = n
Else

        Do
                n = Right(p, (Len(p) - i))
                i = i + 1
        Loop Until IsNumeric(n) = True
        FindNum = n
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Do you want it to return 100 if there are no numbers or do you want it to  return 1?  Your image shows 100.

Comment: Of course for all practical reasons you could wrap it in an `IFERROR(FindNum(),100)`.

Comment: Its output for `r2d2` was `200`, I don't know what to think.

Comment: Your image showed numbers which were all integers - is this the intended application?

Comment: It looks like Alex is anticipating having numbers on the left or right of a string, or no numbers at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
Function FindNum(str As String, Optional FromLeft As Boolean = False, Optional default As Long = 1) As Long
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, pieces As Variant
    Dim ch As String, newstr As String

    n = Len(str)
    For i = 1 To n
        ch = Mid(str, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(ch) Then
            newstr = newstr & ch
        Else
            newstr = newstr & "/"
        End If
    Next i
    pieces = Split(newstr, "/")
    On Error GoTo return_default
    n = UBound(pieces)
    If FromLeft Then
        For i = 0 To n
            If Len(pieces(i)) > 0 Then
                FindNum = Val(pieces(i))
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        For i = n To 0 Step -1
            If Len(pieces(i)) > 0 Then
                FindNum = Val(pieces(i))
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    End If
return_default:
    FindNum = default
End Function
```

This returns the first integer detected in the string from either the left or the right (depending on an optional parameter which makes no difference if only 1 integer is found) and returns a default value if no such number is found.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

I made a similar function. it can read from left to right or right to left and you can set "ertdfgcvb" to be the decimal separator if you so wish.

```
Function FindNum2(num As String, Optional DecimalSeparator As String, Optional FromRight As Boolean) As Double
' text where the number is   | string that works as decimal sep | who the hell wants to read from right to left? if you do, this one's for you
If Len(num) = 0 Then Exit Function
Dim x As String, y As String, DefaultValue As Double
DefaultValue = 1 'here's your default

num = Replace(num, DecimalSeparator, ".")

For i = IIf(FromRight, Len(num), 1) To IIf(FromRight, 1, Len(num)) Step IIf(FromRight, -1, 1)
        y = Mid(num, i, 1) 'the current character
    If y Like "#" Then 'if it's a number
        x = x & y 'then append it
    ElseIf y = "." Then 'if it's a decimal separator
        x = x & y 'then append a decimal separator; if there are multiple of it then tough luck
    End If
Next i
If x = "" Then
    FindNum2 = DefaultValue
Else
    FindNum2 = Val(x) 'converts the string to a double
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your check to a for loop and check each char isNumeric. Then check your counter variable at the end.

```
Function FindNum(parameter, Optional ignore As Variant, Optional side As Variant) As Double
Dim n
Dim i
Dim p
Dim Counter As Integer

i = 0
If IsMissing(ignore) = True Then
    p = parameter
Else

    If side = 1 Then
        p = Right(parameter, (Len(parameter) - Len(ignore)))

    ElseIf side = 0 Then
        p = Left(parameter, (Len(parameter) - Len(ignore)))
    Else
        p = parameter

    End If
End If

For Counter = 1 To Len(p)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(p, Counter, 1)) = True Then
       n = n + Mid(p, Counter, 1)
    End If
Next

If n = "" Then
   FindNum = 1
Else
    FindNum = n
End If

End Function
```